# Shorthand for nullable on return types?

Tags: typescript

I know I can use "name?: type" as shorthand for nullable in many places, but it doesn't seem to work for return types. Is there a way?

```
function veryUsefulFunction(val?: string /* this is OK */)
// but not this or other things I've tried.
// is there a way aside from "|undefined"?
: string?
{
    return val?.toLowerCase();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No, there isn't. It's been discussed in the TypeScript issues list (for instance, [#35577](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/35577)), but decided against.

In many cases, you can just leave off the return type entirely and allow TypeScript to infer it. Sometimes you don't want to do that because you want to catch erroneous edits to the function inadvertently changing its return type, but for simple cases like the above it may be reasonable. The inferred type in that case would be `string | undefined`:

```
function veryUsefulFunction(val?: string) { // Infers `string | undefined`
    return val?.toLowerCase();
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABANwKYCcCeBVAzq0AGwDFxp4wAKZAQ0IH4AuRXKdGMAcwEpEBvAFCJhidKigh0SWgwB0UOABk4AdwwBhGvkrcA3AIC+QA)

Other than that, though, you'd have to use `string | undefined` or the similar `string | void` *([more here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#void))* or a generic (some libraries provide an `Optional` type, for instance, which is basically `type Optional<T> = T | undefined`).

Answer (score 1):

No. The return type doesn't support the `?` operator to indicate that it might be `undefined`

The return type here should be

`string | undefined`